# ansible \ include other yml with param doesn't work

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

why this not working:

```
---
  - hosts: all
    vars:
      input_version: 99

  - include: ./tagger_1.yml input="{{ input_version }}"
```

child is:

```
    ---
  - name: build tagger docker
    hosts: all  
    vars:       
        version: "11.0"
    tasks:
    - name: some step !!!!!!
      command: echo {{ version }}
```

echo prints the child but I wanted to override it with input param from parent. doable?

```
changed: [localhost] => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["echo", "11.0"], "delta": "0:00:00.010476", "end": "2016-06-23 13:21:44.091857", "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "echo 11.0", "_uses_shell": false, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "warn": true}, "module_name": "command"}, "rc": 0, "start": "2016-06-23 13:21:44.081381", "stderr": "", "stdout": "11.0", "stdout_lines": ["11.0"], "warnings": []}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `echo {{ version }}` but in the parent you set the variable input.

If you `command: echo {{ input }}` it should work.

If what you want is to override a var directly defined in the son I dont think you can, due to variable precedence.

**for ansible 1.x**

the precedence is as follows (with the last listed variables winning prioritization):

- “role defaults”, which lose in priority to everything and are the most easily overridden
- variables defined in inventory
- facts discovered about a system
- “most everything else” (command line switches, vars in play, included vars, role vars, etc.)
- connection variables (ansible_user, etc.)
- extra vars (-e in the command line) always win

**for ansible 2.x**

- role defaults
- inventory vars [2]
- inventory group_vars
- inventory host_vars
- playbook group_vars
- playbook host_vars
- host facts
- play vars
- play vars_prompt
- play vars_files
- registered vars
- set_facts
- role and include vars
- block vars (only for tasks in block)
- task vars (only for the task)
- extra vars (always win precedence)

For more information see: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable